# Magento 2: Getting Module validation issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, module, validation

I am getting the module validation error:

```
D:\marketplace-tools>php validate_m2_package.php Abc.zip

ERROR - "Abc.zip": "composer.json" found in unexpected place. Zip archive layout not to standard as described in the "Component File Structure" section of the PHP Developer Guide.
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Please let me know if you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your module files are not in inside of an folder in Zip.

Put your module files in Root of your ZIP file.

**Wrong way**: Abc.zip > MyModule > Module Files

**Correct way**: Abc.zip > Module Files

If above doesn't help, please share your file structure of zip file.